# Inverse of a matrix and small changes

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

This is a reference request, I would like to know where to find results concerning the inverse of a matrix: 
Suppose we have the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $b$. We consider $x = A^{-1}b$. If we now change the last row $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of $A$, how does $x$ change? More specifically, if we exchange $a$ by $b$ such that the Euclidean distance between $a$ and $b$ is strictly greater than some constant $c > 0$, how does this change $x$?

I am interested in any sort of result concerning this type of linear algebra, I would also appreciate references to articles that use linear algebra from a more geometric point of view.

Many thanks.

Comment: Changing the last row of $A$ may result in $\det(A)=0$, so that $x$ no longer is defined.

Comment: You may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number , this is not exactly the problem you stated,but I shown a system in this post which give completely different solution if we change it just a little. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298526/computing-inverse-of-a-matrix-when-a-good-starting-guess-is-available/2298624#2298624

Comment: This is a very general question. If you came upon it from a particular application or for a particular reason you might get help here if you edit the question to show us what problem you want to solve that led to this one.

Comment: This problem is akin to downdating and updating.  In the setting where you have an overdetermined system, one may want to remove an equation in the system (downdate) and/or add an equation to the system (updating).  This has application, for example, where you have a window of measurements to consider.  As new measurements come in (equations are added) the oldest measurements may become less relevant (equations are deleted).

Comment: Thank you all for comments! Dietrich Burde, I can assume that the new column is linearly independent from the others. @zwim, I looked at the condition number, I feel that it goes into the right direction. But I am more interested in some reverse direction (@Ethan Bolker): assume we want to solve (1,0,0)x = 1, (0,1,0)x=1, (0,0,1)x = 2. This is easy. But what happens if we change the last row by (0,1/2,/sqrt{3}/2)? How much does our solution change at least?