# Inverse Matrix or Cramer's Rule?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, approximation, inverse

We consider the system $$\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 2 & 0.5\\ 0 & -20 & 1 \\ 4 & -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ -30\\ 42\end{pmatrix}$$ I have applied the Jacobi method with 3 iterations.

Then I applied the method with the inverse matrix and the Cramer's Rule. At these both methods I don't get the exact same result but approximately the same. Which method of these two is better? With which do we get a better result?

Comment: The Jacobi method finds an approximate solution. (Typically one would use many more than the iterations.) The other two methods you mentioned find an exact solution. But it would be better to just use Gaussian elimination to solve the linear system.

Comment: So both Inverse Matrix method and Cramer's Rule should find the same exact solution? @littleO

Comment: You should get $(1,2,10)^t$. Did you try row reduction?

Comment: System solving by approximative methods (as Jacobi) is very sensitive to error propagation, if the condition number is bad, a small error on the coefficients has huge impact on the solution (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2298624/399263). But starting with integer coefficients (which are exact) you can find solution as rationals which are also exact by any non-approximative method (Cramer, Gauss elimination).